# Serializing with Messagepack

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, msgpack, messagepack

I like to serialize my java class object using [Messagepack](http://msgpack.org/). My class structure is such that

```
public class A
 {
   private InnerClass obj;
   //Some other variables with getters and setters.
   // There will be a getter and setter for obj(InnerClass) aswell.
 }
 class InnerClass
 {
  //Some variables with getters and setters.
 }
 class InnerDerivedClass extends InnerClass
 {
  //some variables with getters and setters.
 }
```

What I like to do is to create the object for InnerDerivedClass and assign some values to it. Then I would add the object to the Class A as base class object.Now when I serialize and deserialize the Class A object with Messagepack I am not able to get the object as InnerDerivedClass object rather its comes as InnerClass obj. How can I achieve this using MessagePack. I am not using any annotations rather I register each class in the messagepack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at documentation and examples of MessagePack and I couldn`t find anything about nested serialization, only simple types and Maps.

I recommend you to use GSON for your problem
1) [Java - Gson parsing nested within nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453006/java-gson-parsing-nested-within-nested)
2) [Deserializing arbitrary object json arrays in inner classes with Gson or nested inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470339/deserializing-arbitrary-object-json-arrays-in-inner-classes-with-gson-or-nested)

You can try use JSON-SIMPLE. It will reprezent you classes as nested Maps
https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/MappingBetweenJSONAndJavaEntities

Answer (score 0):

For nested structures I'd recommend [FlexJson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/); you can avoid all the boiler plate code associated with nested structures:

```
A obj1 = new A()
String json = JSONSerializer().deepSerialize(obj1);

//get back
A obj2 = JSONDeserializer<A>().deserialize(json);
```