# JSON to java object using gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am using GSON library for turing JSON that comes form a web service but I can't make it work, I always get a null. I've looked through similar issues like Converting Json to Java such as [Simple Json to Java convertion using GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981471/simple-json-to-java-convertion-using-gson). But I am still missing something

JSON

```
{"A":"val1","B":"val2","C":"val3","D":"val4","E":"val5","F":"val6","G":"val7"}
         SiteWrapper m = gson.fromJson(json, SiteWrapper.class);
```

java Class

```
SiteWrapper m = gson.fromJson(json, SiteWrapper.class);
System.out.println(m.getMenu());

static class Site {
    static String A;
    static String B;
    static String C;
    static String D;
    static String E;
    static String F;
    static String G;

    public String toString() {
        return String.format(A,B,C,D,E,F,G);}

    public static String getA() {
        return A;
    }
    public static String getB() {
        return B;
    } 
... all the way to getG

    public void setA(String A) {
        Site.A = A;
    }
    public void setB(String B) {
        Site.B = B;
    }
... all the way to setB
```

and my wrapper

```
class SiteWrapper {
    private Site site;
    public Site getMenu() { return site; }
    public void setMenu(Site site) { this.site = site; }
}
```

no matter what I do I get a null printed , any ideas?

Comment: "all the way to setB" I think you mean "setG"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since its a static inner class .As [docs](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Java-Modifier-Exclusion) pointed out and comments :

> As well, if a field is marked as "static" then by default it will be
>   excluded. If you want to include some transient fields...

You may want to try

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .excludeFieldsWithModifier()
    .create();
```

Also, since its a inner class you may need to change your JSON If you can:

```
 {
   "site":{
      "A":"val1",
      "B":"val2",
      "C":"val3",
      "D":"val4",
      "E":"val5",
      "F":"val6",
      "G":"val7"
   }
}
```

As noted here in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470339/deserializing-arbitrary-object-json-arrays-in-inner-classes-with-gson-or-nested)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in your code you're passing `SiteWrapper.class` when you should be passing `Site.class` to `gson.fromJSON`

This line

```
SiteWrapper m = gson.fromJson(json, SiteWrapper.class);
```

should be

```
Site s = gson.fromJSON(json, Site.class);
```

`Site` is the class you defined for the JSON provided.  `SiteWrapper` contains a site variable, you need to set this `Site` variable to the result of the `fromJSON`

Comment: While this is certainly contributing to the issue, this will not work by itself. Statics are excluded by default.

Answer (score 0):

Per [this](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Java-Modifier-Exclusion) documentation, all static fields are excluded by default. Follow the example in the link to alter the default exclusion strategy so that statics are accepted.

When you create your `Gson` object, try the following:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .excludeFieldsWithModifier(Modifier.TRANSIENT,Modifier.VOLATILE)
    .create();
```

This should create a `Gson` object that will not exclude static fields by default.

Comment: You'll need to make both the changes suggested in NuclearGhost's answer, and mine for it work properly.